# how to remove time part

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I want remove the time part. While using the given below code getting the out but like given : **4/27/2015 12:00:00 AM** I want remove the 12:00:00 AM. I tried some methods. but it is not working.
 Code:

```
DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStart.Text);
DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEnd.Text);
var date1 = start .Date;
var date2 = end .Date;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Following Code , the ToDateShortString() will Produce Date:

```
DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStart.Text);
DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEnd.Text);

var date1 = start.ToShortDateString();
var date2 = end.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

try using format function and format to custom date format.

```
DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStart.Text);
DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEnd.Text);
var date1 = format(start.Date,"dd/MM/yyyy");
var date2 = format(end.Date,"dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Now tested and is working fine.use the format which u want.i assume u need `"MM/dd/yyyy"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String test = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyy");
```

else

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString ()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date.

```
String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", start); // output: 4/27/2015
String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", end); // output: 4/27/2015
```